# how to add up values before and after a slash

Tags: r, slash

Hi I have a question related to slash.

the data I'm working on is like:

```
X Y Z
12/22 14/32 22/34
```

I would like to get the mean of the values before and after the slash.

```
X Y Z
17 18 28
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is fairly easy to solve, but you need to do a little bit more of work. Search this site for how to split a string. R has a built-in functionality for this and it should come up in a reasonably simple search.

Comment: You have a string or a data frame there?

Comment: It's a dataframe @DavidArenburg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the mean of each cell even if there are more than one row in the data.frame:

```
as.data.frame(
  apply(dat, 1:2, function(x) {
      mean(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(x,"/"))))
    }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x) mean(c(as.integer(sub("/.+", "", x)), 
                                             as.integer(sub(".+/", "", x))))))
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
values<-c("12/22","14/32","22/34")

> unlist(lapply(strsplit(values,"/"),function(values2){mean(as.numeric(values2))}))
[1] 17 23 28
```